# Why pandas deprecation of iteritems() is influencing the pd.DataFrame().columns?

Tags: python, pandas, series, python-itertools

I have a code that is using pandas everywhere. In various instances, wheather I am using Series or just calling .columns method, I receive this warning:

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2.3\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_utils.py:609: FutureWarning: iteritems is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use .items instead.
  for item in s.iteritems():
```

I am not using iteritems() directly. Why do I have this warning message?

Should I worry about it? Will my code be compatible with future versions?

Comment: can you show the line of your code that throws the warning please?

Comment: It looks like it has been solved because I cannot replicate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely, it is caused by "old" version of Pycharm that you use.
If the issue will occur again, please try with updating your Pycharm version to at least 2022.3.1.
For more details have a look on:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-56361/FutureWarning-pandas.Series.iteritems-in-pydevdutils.py

Comment: I have an auto-update of PyCharm. Maybe that was a problem. I cannot recall how to replicate that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may not use the iteritems() directly, but your code refers to a library which does, in pydevd_utils.py

If it works, there is nothing to worry about for the current version, but of course this won't be future proof and will fail e.g. if you install pandas 2.0.0.

Answer (score -2):

This is the future warning, and as suggested, use `s.items()` instead of `s.iteritems()`